# Какие версии Windows поддерживают приложение WF или Windows Service на Net Core 3.00?

Tags: windows, winforms, .net-core

Какие версии Windows поддерживают приложение Winforms или Windows Service на Net Core 3.00?

Comment: [docs.microsoft.com](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/3.0/3.0-supported-os.md)

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо